# Hive join with OR condition

Tags: hive

I've got pretty big table `TAB1` and I need to select rows from it which match conditions

```
(TAB1.KEY1 = TAB2.KEY1 OR TAB1.KEY1 = TAB2.KEY2) AND TAB1.KEY2 = TAB2.KEY3
```

where `TAB2` is a very little table.

I can't do it just by joining these two tables in hive because hive doesn't support joins with OR conditions. I tried to separate these condition by using union clause but it seems it's much more expensive because of two joins with big table.

Is there any better way to do the job? P.S. I use hive 0.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to join using hive map side join-

```
select /*+ MAPJOIN(TAB2) */ t1.* from TAB1 t1 join TAB2 on t1.KEY2 = t2.KEY3
where t1.KEY1 = t2.KEY1 OR t1.KEY1 = t2.KEY2
```

Comment: Ugly variation on that theme: `select /*+ MapJoin(Yuck) */ t1.* from TAB1 t1 join (select distinct KEY12, KEY3 from (select KEY1 as KEY12, KEY3 from TAB2 union all select KEY2, KEY3 from TAB2) Yack) Yuck on Yuck.KEY12 =t1.KEY1 and Yuck.KEY3 =t1.KEY2`

Comment: As of Hive 0.11, the MAPJOIN hint is inferred from an optimization that queries table size before peforming the join.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-EnhancementsinHiveVersion0.11

Answer (score 1):

Map joins should be only used on the assumption one table is much smaller than the other and I don't think that's the case here.
However, the solutions that mention map side join also have the actual generic solution, that is, changing the query from a JOIN to a JOIN/WHERE combination.

```
SELECT ... FROM TAB1 JOIN TAB2 ON (TAB1.KEY2 = TAB2.KEY3 )  
    WHERE (TAB1.KEY1 = TAB2.KEY1 OR TAB1.KEY1 = TAB2.KEY2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Roberto. Do you it's better way to join rather than union?